# GlassMapper SC nullable boolean fields causing Failed item resolve

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, glass-mapper

We have recently upgraded from Glass.Sitecore.Mapper 2.0.12.0 to Glass.Mapper.Sc 3.3.1.53 (we can't upgrade any higher as we are using Sitecore 6).

We are having problem with saving items with nullable boolean fields
i.e.

```cs
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = Templates.Category)]
public class Category : AggregateBase
{
    ...

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = CategoryFields.Requires360)]
    public virtual bool? Requires360 { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = CategoryFields.RequiresCatwalk)]
    public virtual bool? RequiresCatwalk { get; set; }
}
```

Where AggregateBase contains the standard sitecore fields
e.g.

```cs
[SitecoreType]
public class AggregateBase
{
    [SitecoreId]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    [SitecoreInfo(SitecoreInfoType.Name)]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

   ...
}
```

If the nullable bool field is null it saves without issue.

If the nullable field has a value we get the following exception

> "Failed item resolve - You cannot save a class that does not contain a
>   property that represents the item ID. Ensure that at least one
>   property has been marked to contain the Sitecore ID. Type:
>   System.Boolean"

This configuration worked previously and seems to work with other nullable types e.g. int?

The underlying storage in the template field is "Single-Line Text".

Does anyone have any ideas?

Regards,

Mark

Comment: Why do you use `Single-Line Text` field for a bool value? Have you tried to use `Checkbox` field? Or not-nullable property with `Checkbox` field?

Comment: I am just upgrading the code so I don't know why the original decision was made to store it in "Single-Line Text".  I have worked around the issue by making the glass mapper fields string then adding some wrapper properties that convert it to a nullable boolean.